# Drag and drop upload any object file and display it in threejs

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I'm wanting to load an object file of any type and show it with the browser side three js library. I have included a basic template for html that includes a drag and drop box with an upload button along with a div that shows a basic geometry in threejs (provided by three).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>

        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">

            
                <div class="form-group files">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" multiple="">
                </div>

        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class='showObject'>
                <script>
                    function gotFile(file) {
                        var object = new Object();

                        object.onload = function () {
                        document.body.appendChild(this);
                        };

                        object.src = file.data;
                    }
                </script>
                <script src="js/three.js"></script>
                <script>
                    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
                    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
        
                    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        
                    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
                    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
                    const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                    scene.add( cube );
        
                    camera.position.z = 5;
        
                    const animate = function () {
                        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        
                        cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
                        cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
        
                        renderer.render( scene, camera );
                    };
        
                    animate();
                </script>

            </div>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm getting a little lost as in the documentation there is a lot of mention about loading files and images and objects etc. I know that it is possible to load a glb object from a local file path. But the file path doesn't exist until the upload has been confirmed.
for example:

```
const loader = new GLTFLoader();

loader.load( 'path/to/model.glb', function ( gltf ) {

    scene.add( gltf.scene );

}, undefined, function ( error ) {

    console.error( error );

} );
```

Am i missing something here?

Comment: I think you have to use loader.parse instead of loader.load. You're manually loading the file, only have to parse it.

Comment: @EthanHermsey thanks for that. My problem with that is the object needs to be in json format. So would I need to convert the file of and object file type to json?

Comment: I don't believe so. You should be able to load the GLB file as an Arraybuffer ( practially the raw file ) and pass that in as the first argument in .parse(). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer